# How should we handle questions with ethical concerns?

Tags: discussion

A recent question<sup>†</sup> started me thinking about whether, as a site, we wanted to declare questions with obvious legal and ethical problems to be off-topic.

<sup>† [What open source software and hardware can be used to build autonomous weapon system similar to Super aEgis II?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/8838/37)</sup>

Allowing questions which relate to the specifics of autonomous weapons systems, or export restricted technologies for instance could potentially land us in hot water, but equally we don't want to stifle questions on topics which may be of interest to many people.

Currently, our [What topics can I ask about here?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page doesn't mention anything regarding the ethics or legalities of questions here, but I would be happy to consider suggestions for changes to the wording.

Also related:

- [Should we allow legal questions?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16/37)

Comment: Another example: [Scan an Auditorium, Count People, and Display Open Seats](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/14226/37)